# How to insert data(to a database) from a text document using Asp.net

Tags: asp.net

In my application,i want to check a condition whether the 'ENTER' key is pressed or not.i want to read data from a text file and insert this data to my database.I have written my code in a button-click event.In the text file, every field is separated by a comma so that each field can be identified.After one record,'ENTER' key is pressed and next record is written in next line.so i want to insert each row in the database until the next line.i suppose i can check this with the ASCII code of "Enter"  key.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please explain what you mean by "using ASCII code".

Comment: @heinzi i think Nandu is talking about keyCode and charCode

Comment: @Pandiya: That's possible. I still don't understand what he wants to do, though.

Comment: @heinzi if he edits we ll get an idea what he wants..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are reading from a text file, the easiest solution is to use the [ReadLine method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textreader.readline.aspx) of a `StreamReader`, which returns the next line from the text file. No need to check for ENTER ASCII codes.

```
Using sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader("path\to\your\file.txt")
    Do While sr.Peek() >= 0
        Dim line As String = sr.ReadLine()   ' Read one line (until next ENTER) from the file
        Dim values As String() = line.Split(","c)    ' Split the line at the commas

        ...   ' Write the data of the "values" array into your database
    Loop
End Using
```

Comment: ya,i have used this to split the fields.but for inserting the second row,i have to check whether the second row has arrived or not.for that,in the text file,the 2nd row to the database is written in the next line after pressing the Enter key.thats why i need the ASCII code checking.Can you please give the code for ASCII checking?it will definitely solve my problem.

Comment: @Nandu: I still don't understand why you need this instead of ReadLine, but if you are sure it will solve your problem, here you go: An ENTER key in Windows is represented by two characters in sequence: CR and LF. They can be found in the VB constants `vbCr` and `vbLf` (there's also `vbCrLf`, a string containing both). Thus, you can check `If someCharacter = vbCr OrElse someCharacter = vbLf Then`. If you need the numerical ASCII code, it's 13 for CR and 10 for LF.

Answer (score 0):

try this,Call on key down event of your form/control
****if e.keyCode=keys.Enter then
----------- do something -----
end if ****

Comment: no,i have no key down event for my button.only button_click is possible

Comment: can you suggest an alternative method for this?